# Creating SAR file with Ant

Tags: ant, sar

I am reworking a build, and notice that the ear file contains a Service archive file (sar). I'd like to build the sar file in Ant. I suspect I could probably use the `ear` or `zip` task to do this, and simply name the file as `*.sar`. However, I want to be sure that this will work.

What task would I use in Ant to create a SAR file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you should use the standard JAR task in ANT. According to the JBoss documentation, SAR files contain an extra file:

- [META-INF/jboss-service.xml](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ServiceArchive)

The following "hello world" example has a sample project attached:

- https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExampleHelloWorldService

Comment: Thanks.  I know the `ear`, `war`, and `jar`tasks are all based upon the `zip` task. I figured worse comes to worse, I can use the `zip` task -- if the `sar` is a zip type of archive. I just wanted to make sure. I thought the `ear` task would be the closest and I just set the `appxml` parameter to the `java-service.xml` file. However, I've found other examples that use the `jar` task, so that's what I'll use.

Answer (score 0):

A sar file is a special kind of jar file (with certain files in WEB-INF, etc.).  So you can use the `jar` task, e.g.:

```
<jar destfile="${sar.filename}">...</jar>
```